# Will extjs4.2.2 supports pivot tables

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to include a pivot table in my web application, I am using extjs4.2.2. I need to know whether this capability is available in this version of extjs4.2.2

Comment: Removed extra tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officialy supported Pivot Grid component is now a part of [ExtJS Premium edition](https://www.sencha.com/store/extjs/) package. Besides, it is included into a trial [version](https://www.sencha.com/products/evaluate/), so you can download and test it in your application as a separate module.

Comment: I have seen that extjs-3.* version support PivotGrid, but it is unavailable in extjs-4.2.2 version, is there any way I can implement PivotGrid functionality in extjs-4.2.2?? Providing the link for extjs3.3 version Pivot Grid                                                                                                               http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/pivotgrid/simple.html

Comment: It may take you quite a lot to implement it by yourself. Why don't you simple use ext-3.3.0 pivot grid or from extjs-6? Just build a brand new module with a pivot grid.

Comment: Actually I have implemented many other parts of my application using extjs-4.2.2 version which is unavailable in 3.3. And migration to 6 is not possible during this time?? Can you provide some sample code which implement pivot table using extjs-4.2.2